# Swift: Adding a UIButton in each cell while having a UITableViewCell in the code but not in the storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a list of tracks, which represents list of tasks stored in the array, anyways, I need to have a button next to each that is named "Track" So that the user can track to this task by moving to another page that has this functions.
My problem is that I couldn't make the button displayed next to each cell.
the code of displaying the information in table view:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = trackMgr.tracks[indexPath.row].name

    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(trackMgr.tracks[indexPath.row].score)

    return cell



}
```

This is what my table view looks like in the storyboard:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkPHr.png)

What I tried to do is declaring "mybutton" that equals UIButton! at the top, and then calling cell.mybutton.text = "text" but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use following code for creating button on every cell and accordingly you can perform track task after pressing buttons.

Have a look on following code

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = "hello"
    let track_Button = UIButton()
    track_Button.setTitle("Track", forState: .Normal)
    track_Button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
    track_Button.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-100, 0, 100, 40)
    track_Button.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    track_Button.addTarget(self, action: "track_Button_Pressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    cell.addSubview(track_Button)

    return cell


}

func track_Button_Pressed(sender: UIButton!) {

    // Track Functionality
    println("Add Track Functionality here")
}
```